# By default Selecting dropdown value conditionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown with 2 options `Month & Year`. Based on API call response, If `period == Y`, Year should be selected by default & if `period == M`, Month should be selected.
I dont know how to do this.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 PDL dateY">
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1" ng-model="SelectedValue_free" ng-options="details.period for details in validity_dd">
    </select>
</div>    

 $scope.validity_dd = [
    {
        period: 'Year'
    }, {
     period: 'Month'
    }
]
```

Comment: You got null value in your dropdown right ?

Comment: Because of  ng-model variable is not declare in js file so, getting null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your condition after you get the information from the api, set

```
 if(period == 'Y') 
 $scope.SelectedValue_free= 'Year';
 else if(period == 'M') 
 $scope.SelectedValue_free= 'Month';
```

Change you ng-options to ,

```
 ng-options="details.period as details.period for details in validity_dd"
```

OR you can set

```
 if(period == 'Y') 
 $scope.SelectedValue_free= $scope.validity_dd[0];
 else if(period == 'M') 
 $scope.SelectedValue_free= $scope.validity_dd[1];


ng-options="details.period for details in validity_dd"
```

Comment: There is a blank option is coming in dropdown options. No value is getting selected.

Comment: Try to change the ng-option expression

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script in app.js

```
$scope.validity_dd = [
    {
        period: 'Year'
    }, {
     period: 'Month'
    }
]   

//this is an array to store all the possible options as key value pairing
$scope.opt_arr={'Y':'Year','M':'Month'};

//Here you can set the value of period with api call response data
$scope.period='M';

//this will search the object from the array which match the data
var result = $.grep($scope.validity_dd, function(e)
            { return e.period == $scope.opt_arr[$scope.period]; });

//this will set the model value so that the required option will be selected
$scope.SelectedValue_free=result[0];
```